# add apex trigger and visualforce page to an unmanaged package

Tags: visualforce, trigger, package, unmanaged-package

I am working in a `sandbox` where i created several items: `Custom object`, `trigger, test class, visualforce page`, ...etc

And i created an `unmanaged package` in `Setup->create->Package` and when i try to add my `trigger` or the `visualforce` page, it doesn't allow me to do it : When i click the button `ADD` and i select from the list Apex Trigger i can't see the trigger i created : same problem for the `visualforce page`.

Any solution to this problem ?

**Note**:
i added successfully to my package the custom object and the test class of trigger

Comment: What do you mean it "wold not let me do it" be specific

Comment: when i click the button `ADD` and i select from the list `Apex Trigger` i can't see the trigger i created.

There are many triggers but not the one i created : same case for the visualforce page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not see them in ADD menu, but they should already be included in the package. You added your Custom object, so related VF pages, classes and triggers were added automatically as well. Please check your package components list!

Comment: Yes, when i added my custom object and other items, many other elements appear in the components list including the trigger.